# Automatically reduce MacBook brightness on connecting to external display?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, applescript, automator, automation

I would like my macbook to reduce its screen brightness to zero when I connect it to an external display. I know there's no such setting, but how would I go about writing a script that would do that?

The reason for brightness reduction is that I don't use macbook's screen when I connect an external display and I often forget to reduce brightness on it. Would be great if it reduced the brightness itself.

Comment: Simply close the lid and you're done? No screen with light, no script. Just easy!

Comment: Yea clamshell mode FTW!

Comment: @Robuust would've worked, but I need to use the trackpad.